# Extracting Raw JSON as String inside a Spray POST route

Tags: json, scala, rest, post, spray

I've a POST Spray route and the request contains a JSON body (content-type "application/json"). I want a way to extract the raw JSON from this request inside my route.

For http://host:port/somepath/value1 I want to *extract* the post body as `TextMsgResponse`. But for http://host:port/somepath/value2 I want to *extract* the post body just as a raw Json (e.g., `{ "name":"Jack", "age":30 }`

```
val myRoute = path("somepath" / Segment) { pathSegment => 
post {   //use only POST requests
  pathSegment match {
    case "value1" =>
      entity(as[TextMsgResponse]) { textMsg =>
        complete {
          //do something with the request
          StatusCodes.OK
        }
      } 
    case "value2" => { 
       //here is I want to extract the RAW JSON from the request          
      } 
    }
   }
```

Comment: Have you tried `entity(as[Array[Byte]])` or `entity(as[String])`?

Comment: Yes and both of them don't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [extract](http://spray.io/documentation/1.1-SNAPSHOT/spray-routing/basic-directives/extract/) directive as

```
def rawJson = extract { _.request.entity.asString} 
    .
    .
    . 
case "value2" => rawJson{ json =>// use the json 
  }
```